# Jquery setTimeout not working if used without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing this code.

```
$('.mcqtd').click(function(){
var choice = this.id;   
    checkanswer(choice,questions[x].correctAnswer);
    window.setTimeout(showquestion(x+1,0),3000); // 1 seconds
});

}

function checkanswer(answer,original){
    if (answer=='choice'+original){
        $('#choice'+original).css('backgroundColor', '#DD792E');
        $('#choice'+original).append("<span class='padding10 mcqsymbol'><img src='images/right_icon.png' /></span>");
    } else {
        $('#'+answer).css('backgroundColor', '#AFA689');
        $('#'+answer).append("<span class='padding10 mcqsymbol'><img src='images/wrong_icon.png' /></span>");
        $('#choice'+original).css('backgroundColor', '#DD792E');
        $('#choice'+original).append("<span class='padding10 mcqsymbol'><img src='images/right_icon.png' /></span>");
    }
}
```

`Onclick`, the `tds` should be highlighted, and after 3 seconds, the next question should be loaded but this is not happening, after 3 seconds the next question is being loaded, but backgrounds are not changing. If I alert something inside `checkanswer()`, the code works. Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The to executing part must be wrapped in a anonymous function if you want to use parametes. Otherwise it is not working in `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    showquestion(x + 1, 0);
}, 3000);
```

As [A.Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) noted in the comments below, you can even pass parameters to a called function in `setTimeout` by extening the parameters behind the time.

```
// note there are no '()' behind the function name
setTimeout(showquestion, 3000, x + 1, 0);
```

If you would call a function without parameters you can left out the wrapper function and the additional parameters too.

```
// note there are no '()' behind the function name
setTimeout(functionWithoutParameter, 3000);
```

Comment: Side note: the reason that setTimeout won't work, is because it calls the first argument after 3000 ms. When calling showquestion(x+1,0) before, it will return undefined (there is no return) and setTimeout will try to call undefined after 3000 ms.

Comment: Just as a side note, you can still pass parameter to callback function without using any wrapper: `setTimeout(showquestion, 3000, x+1, 0);`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

What you do is calling the function directly and passing it's return value over to `setTimeout`. As you intend to use arguments with this, you will have to make use of an *anonymous function*, eg:

```
setTimeout(function(){ showquestion(x+1, 0);}, 3000);
```

**Edit:**

If you only have a functioncall without arguments it woulf look like:

```
setTimeout("foo()", 3000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(foo, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirtly call this in setTimeout method its not working.

```
  setTimeout(question, 3000);

   function question() {
     showquestion(x + 1, 0)
   }
```